# LINQ sub-select Error

Tags: c#, linq, select

I have object with this structure.

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public string idProduct { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public List<WarehouseItem> WarehouseInfo = new List<WarehouseItem>();
}

public class WarehouseItem
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string LocnCode{ get; set; }
}
```

I need to get all `LocnCode` and make distinct by them so in result it should be `List<string>`.
I am trying do this

```
List<string> codes = itemList.Select(x => x.WarehouseInfo.Select(y => y.LocnCode)).Distinct();
```

but have this Error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'.`

How to do it?

Comment: the error comes because you miss a `.ToList()`. But not sure you will retrieve what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) to flatten the hierarchy:

```
List<string> distinctCodes = itemList
      .SelectMany(x => x.WarehouseInfo)
      .Select(y => y.LocnCode)
      .Distinct()
      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> codes = itemList.SelectMany(x => x.WarehouseInfo)
                             .Select(y => y.LocnCode)
                             .Distinct()
                             .ToList();
```

Or even change little bit from your code using [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

```
List<string> codes = itemList.SelectMany(x => x.WarehouseInfo
                                               .Select(y => y.LocnCode))
                             .Distinct()
                             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Other version:

```
var query = from order in items
            from warehouse in order.WarehouseInfo 
            select warehouse.LocnCode ;

List<string> codes = query.Distinct().ToList();
```